# I am working on a bot that can mute some with a code, but when i do the command it doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

So I have been working on a discord bot, that mutes people. now I've got everything but, it doesn't say anything, doesn't mute them, please help

```
import discord
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="~")

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@bot.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx,member : discord.Member):
  muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role=807271372035850320

  await member.add_roles(muted_role)

  await ctx.send(member.mention + " has been muted")
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Comment: Welcome, at first glance I see `get_role` is a function so it needs parentheses instead of assignment. Try using `muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(807271372035850320)`. [Here is the spec](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.Guild.get_role). Please let us know if the issue persists after this change

Answer (score 0):

Since you have

```
client = discord.Client()
```

All your commands should begin with

```
@client.command()
```

Otherwise change it to:

```
bot = discord.Bot()
```

This should work too

Comment: Can you give me example I'm kinda new to this

Comment: since you have 'client = discord.Client()' your mute command should change from ' @bot.command(aliases=['m'])' to ' @client.command(aliases=['m'])'

Comment: also I think for aliases you will have to write async def _mute and also insert the word mute in aliases like this: ' @client.command(aliases=['m', 'mute'])' Otherwise you can mute only with ~m

Comment: Ok, will try it tomorrow

Comment: SO i tried and now its giving me this message
Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 13, in <module> @client.command(aliases=['m']) AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'